# Cross domain access with Jax-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

Is this enough to allow other domain to access this resource:

```
@Override
public Response signIn() {
    //ACAO = Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    Response resp = Response.ok("{ 'login' : 'ok'}").header(ACAO, "*").build();
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: Adam Bien Recently released a library to allow Cross Domain Access for JAX-RS applications. Se the blog post here: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/cors_for_jax_rs_2

Comment: Thanks! I makes the code cleaner and more lean

Comment: Should I add an answer?

Comment: Yes, sure, so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case is better to use an already tested implementation. [Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/) recently released a library to allow Cross Domain Access for JAX-RS applications. Se the blog post here: [CORS FOR JAX-RS 2.0 / JAVA EE 7 RELEASED](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/cors_for_jax_rs_2)